# How to place one item (or Text()) on the top right of another item (or Text()) below a Column()?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to place one item (or `Text()`) on the top right of another item (or `Text()`) below a `Column()` ?

In `ListView()` for `Text()`, that works with `textAlign: TextAlign.right` but that didn't work in `Column()`.

I want something like this in the column :

[image]

my code :

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(18),
          child: Text(
            "Age : ",
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(
            "29",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

It works in `ListView()` but it is not working in `Column()` in a `ListView()`.

Comment: add your code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(18),
            child: Text(
              "Age : ",
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text(
              "29",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This way, you align the container element inside the column.
You could also wrap your Text element with Align() if you don't want the Container to be on the right.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          "Age : ",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          "29",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```